# Java - Apache POI - Trouble filling rows and cells with loops (Excel)

Tags: java, excel, loops, apache-poi

There's a HashMap:

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> matrix = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
```

I want to fill an excel sheet in this pattern:

```
hashkey1 | hashkey2 | hashkey3 | hashkey4
value1-1 | value2-1 | value3-1 | value4-1  
value1-2 | value2-2 | value3-2 | value4-2  
value1-3 | value2-3 | value3-3 | value4-3  
value1-4 | value2-4 | value3-4 | value4-4  
value1-5 | value2-5 | value3-5 | value4-5
```

The "hashKeys" are "Categories", and every key has its own ArrayList. Every string-element of the ArrayLists shall be drawn under its correspondent key.

Here's the actual code:

```
int keyCell = -2;
int row = 5;
Row keyRow = worksheet.createRow(4);
Row valueRow = null;
for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> e : matrix.entrySet()) {           
    keyRow.createCell(keyCell += 2).setCellValue(e.getKey());
    for (String s : e.getValue()) { 
        if ((row - 5) < (e.getValue().size())) {
            valueRow = worksheet.createRow(row += 1);
            valueRow.createCell(keyCell).setCellValue(s);
            } else {
                valueRow.createCell(keyCell).setCellValue(s);
            }
        }
    }
```

It works beautifully, except for the fact that the result goes in this pattern:

```
hashkey1 | hashkey2 | hashkey3 | hashkey4
value1-1 |          |          |            
value1-2 |          |          |            
value1-3 |          |          |           
value1-4 |          |          |           
value1-5 | value2-5 | value3-5 | value4-5
```

I think it is working exactly how I want, but the cells get erased at each loop because of the new row that is created at each loop. This is a very challenging problem. I had huge difficulty to come to this, and now I'm absolutely stuck. Nothing works. The cells ALWAYS get erased.

Well, I hope this is a not too prolix topic. I really thank you all for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the inner for loop, keyCell never changes value.  This means you are writing to the same cell value each time.  (I'm surprised the code works at all due to this problem.)

```
 for (String s : e.getValue()) { 
        if ((row - 5) < (e.getValue().size())) {
            valueRow = worksheet.createRow(row += 1);
            valueRow.createCell(keyCell).setCellValue(s);
            } else {
                valueRow.createCell(keyCell).setCellValue(s);
            }
        }
```

So first, I'd fix this problems and use keyCell++.  If that doesn't work, add debugging showing the row and keyCell number each time you call createCell().  This will show if the indexes are following the correct pattern or not.  You want the pattern:

- 0, 0
- 0, 1
- ....
- 0, 4
- 1, 0
- etc

Comment: I increment keyCell by 2 because I need a gap between every key (I'll insert a boolean value there por each ArrayList-Value). So, I can't use "keyCell++". Considering that the keyCell gets updated in the outerloop, if I change its value in the inner loop, I get a completely different pattern.

Comment: Ok then keyCell+=2.  The point is that keyCell needs to be changed inside the loop.  Because right now it is writing to the same cell multiple times.

Comment: I'll analyse deeply this point that you pointed out to me. I'll put the code here if I find the solution. I thank you very much, Jeanne.

Comment: You're right!! It is the keyCell... But it's very very hard to update it inside the inner loop, because I depend of it's value in the outer loop, because it is the right one. But I need to update it in order to avoid the "erasing problem", and this is very confusing.

Comment: It is almost impossible because the inner loop iterates over the size of the array inside the HashMap, and this size has nothing to do with the keyCell numbers. I use the keyCell inside the inner loop to get the right position to place the values under each key.

Comment: As you've noted, you'll need to refactor your code to avoid this problem.  Or use a different data structure that better matches the requirement.